# LinqDataSource: How to assign IQueryable value to where parameters in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linqdatasource

I am trying to assign linq datasource in code behind but I have IQueryable query want to assign in where clouse using Any function like a sub query clause in sql

this is my sql statment

```
select * from table1 where col1 in (select col1 from table1 where col2 like '%xx%')
```

how to convert this clouse to bind it into linq datasource code behind

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this query in linq.

```
 var result = from c in db.table1
   where db.table1.Any(e => e.col2.Contain("xx"))
   select c;
```

Comment: i know how to convert it but linqDataSource.Select accept string parameter i need to pass it into where parameter in code behind
i did n't ask to convert sql to linq

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to call .ToList() on the query that returns IQueryable.